# WM_CREATE and MainWindow

Tags: c++, winapi, window, win32gui

I have seen some examples on the internet where buttons were created under WM_CREATE and I have done some projects where creating "some" buttons such as Start/Stop buttons or Text Fields had to be created under MainWindow and not under WM_CREATE.

Is there any reason for chosing/difference/benefit of the choice of one over other when we can chose between these two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know anything about the Win32Gui library in particular, but I've used plenty of Win32 wrapper libraries and even written one myself.

Handling the [`WM_CREATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632619.aspx) message (which is sent to a window after it is created) is the typical way of creating dynamic child windows such as button controls. This would be the same regardless of whether you're working directly with the Win32 API or using a wrapper library. The only difference might be how that wrapper library expects you to handle the message. For example, in MFC, you would override a member function of the window class called `OnWmCreate`.

But you really can create child windows *anywhere* in the code. You aren't forced to do it in response to `WM_CREATE`. You could do it in response to `WM_KEYDOWN` if you wanted. The only requirement is that you must have already created the parent window (because you must pass a valid handle to the parent window when creating the child window).

It sounds to me like the `MainWindow` you're talking about is the *constructor* method for your `MainWindow` class (a C++ object that models a Win32 window). Depending on the design of the framework, this may or may not be a valid place to create child windows. It depends on that above-stated requirement: whether the underlying Win32 window represented by the C++ object has already been created and whether you have a valid handle to it available inside of the constructor body.

Some frameworks implement a two-phase style of construction for window objects. What I mean by that is that the class constructor creates an instance of a C++ object, and then you need to call a second member function (e.g. `Create`) to create the Win32 window represented by the C++ object. In cases like this, you cannot create child windows inside of the parent window's constructor because the parent window has not yet been created and you do not have a valid handle to use when creating the children.

Other frameworks might require that you specify all of the necessary parameters to create the underlying Win32 window when creating your C++ object, and then the constructor will take care of creating both the C++ object *and* the underlying Win32 window (e.g. by calling the `CreateWindow` function). If the creation of either fails, an exception will be thrown. Otherwise, you can be sure that you have access to a valid window handle inside the body of your derived class's constructor.

However, even if this single-phase approach to construction describes the design of your wrapper library, I would still suggest creating child windows in response to the `WM_CREATE` message, rather than in the constructor. But that's just a personal preference and a matter of individual style.

[Different people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399619/should-a-c-constructor-do-real-work) have [different ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293967/how-much-work-should-be-done-in-a-constructor) about [how much work should be done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905784/what-not-to-do-in-a-constructor) inside of a constructor. My personal litmus test is that, after the constructor has run, you should have a valid, fully usable object on which any member functions can be called. I don't much care for two-phase construction, because I don't like the interface complexity that introduces of requiring the consumer to not only create the object, but also call a `Create` or `Init` method. I don't consider child windows to be an integral part of the parent, though, so I say that their creation belongs elsewhere than in the parent's constructor.

I cannot understand why you say

> I have done some projects where creating "some" buttons such as Start/Stop buttons or Text Fields had to be created under MainWindow and not under WM_CREATE.

There is no reason why you would *have* to create child windows in the constructor and you would be unable or it would not work to do so in response to the `WM_CREATE` message.