# Is there a way to have async constructor in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

Is there a way or a trick to implement async constructor in python?
I know we can't do the thing I typed below but I mean something with this functionality. If no, what is the concept behind this that doesn't let it be async?
thanks in advance.

```
async def __init__(self, param):
    result = await my_method(param)

async def my_method(param):
    # do something async
```

Comment: A constructor shouldn't really be doing work so intense that it's asynchronous…

Comment: @deceze could you explain to me why such intense works should'nt be done in constructor?

Comment: It's generally a good idea to keep your constructors light. Link to further opinions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23623981/476

Comment: I'm using some async database drivers that return cursors. Would be nice to get all the items with `all_items = await list(cursor)` instead of the current method which is a await loop everywhere and appending to a list. Though 3.6 looks like it's going to introduce `all_items = [i for await i in cursor]` https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0530/

Comment: Note: `__init__` is called initializer, `__new__` is a constructor

Comment: I'd recognize __new__ in Python an **allocator** instead of **constructor**. While in C++ new is no doubt a constructor, as you have **placement new** besides allocators.